# Why do functions in c++ need pointers to work (pass by value,pass by reference)

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have a question in c++.I 'am a newbie and was coding the other day in c++, more specifically i was trying to implement some functions (1 that adds 2 numbers and 1 that swaps 2 numbers).

I realized that the code implementing the addition function didn't need no pointers (void func), while the swap function only worked after i used pointers both in parameters of the function and variables used to implement it(int type func).

Any suggestions as to why is this happening? 
Does it have to do with passing by value or by reference and if yes when do we really need to use pointers in these functions?

Comment: Can you include some code for examples? This is just a lot of words with no particular context to latch on to.

Comment: C++ generally steers towards solutions that use references, especially `const` references, but it can still use pointers where appropriate or necessary. You'll need to give us a more specific example here to analyse.

Comment: You can make a swap function without pointers but this will only swap the variables inside the function [not the variables outside it]. In order to swap variables outside it you need to pass the address of those variables.

Comment: @AbdelbakiBoukerche thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your title, functions don't **need** pointers to work:

```
int add(int a, int b)  
{
  return a + b;
}
```

In C++ the rule for passing parameters is to pass a copy of the variables, unless told otherwise.  When passing by copy (a.k.a. pass by value), the parameters cannot be modified.

Rather than passing copies of large data structures (anything that doesn't fit into the processor's register), C++ allows you to pass a reference to the object.  The reference is usually a lot smaller in size than the object it refers to.  Also, passing by reference allows you to modify the original object:

```
bool divide(int a, int b, float& result)
{
  if (b == 0) return false;
  result = static_cast<double>(a) / static_cast<double>(b);
  return true;
}
```

Passing by pointers is similar to passing by reference.  However, a pointer can point to anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Functions take arguments because they do not have direct access to your variables. When you pass only the values to a function (i.e. `void func(int a, int b){ ... }`), the function still does not have access to your variables. What you are doing is basically creating new variables within the function that have the same values as the ones you passed in.
When you pass a pointer, though, you are telling the function where the actual variable is in memory, so it can tinker with the variable even though it is not in its scope (this can be easy to mess up and is the reason higher level languages don't have user-level pointers).

Comment: thanks a lot that seems to be the case thank you very much !